# Is there a way to request new Tor identity in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs, tor

I'm trying to use PhantomJS to scrape a website meanwhile using Tor to change my IP address. I'd like to know is there a way to request new Tor identities in Javascript. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585681/request-new-identify-from-tor-in-javascript) but cannot understand how to use AJAX to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't exactly "do it in AJAX". Rather, you use AJAX to call a server side script that does whatever it is you are trying to do. In this case that means writing an AJAX request to a PHP script that calls the function you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use server side javascript, Node JS.  Use a linux server and run 
`apt-get install tor`

This will create a daemon proxy on your server in which you can have PhantomJS connect to.